# Multi-Module Maven projects design considerations

Tags: java, maven, build

I am looking to create a web project,

This web project will have several modules

> - m1
> - m2
> - m3
> - m4
> - m5

My web project is maven project and so I read about multi-module project.

My questions are

1. Can I package my web project into seperate war's such that P1 contains {m1,m2,m3} while P2 contains {m1,m4,m5}

   - i.e. Create two different deliverables based on what modules I want to deliver
2. Is their any reference regarding considerations that I need to know for designing m1, m2 ... m5
3. How do I setup build process to such project modules

Answer (score 1):

For your request you should create the structure of the project like this:

```
+-- root (pom.xml)
     +-- m1 (pom.xml)
     +-- m2 (pom.xml)
     +-- m3 (pom.xml)
     +-- m4 (pom.xml)
     +-- m5 (pom.xml)
     +-- P1 (pom.xml)
     +-- P2 (pom.xml)
```

and within P1 you give simply the dependencies to the modules you like to package into this module like this:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-one</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-two</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-three</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

If you like having different dependencies in the P2 just simply give other dependencies within P2.
Based on your second question i can only say just do it as best as in java. Use interface to decouple modules etc. And separate the modules based on general intention/function like:

```
   +-- core
   +-- base
   +-- web1
   +-- api
```

etc. It's hard to answer this in general without any real realtionship may be giving an example might help.
To your third question i can recomment to read the [Maven Complete Reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit) etc. and not to forget the web sites about maven etc.